# How to Create a URL to an mvc Action in a Different WebForm Project in the Same Solution?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two projects one asp.net mvc and one webform in the same solution. You would know if you can use both the web projects. Specifically, it would be able to use some of the action mvc project in the webform project.

Comment: Please add some code and some examples of what you want to do.

Comment: I want to create a menu item in the webform project that will allow me to open the page of a wild mvc project and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing is *project*-specific. Regardless of whether your projects share the same solution, there's no easy way to generate a URL from one project in another. This is mostly due to the fact that other factors play into what URLs are generated by project other than just the routes it defines, such as virtual directories, domains, etc. These things are only known by the specific project while it is running.

As a result, the only way to truly get the URL for a route from a project is to get it from *that* project, while it is running. That means, you need to set up some sort of endpoint that you can send an HTTP request to, which would return an appropriate URL. Then, in your other project, you would have to use something like `HttpClient` to issue a request to that endpoint with whatever information it would need to generate the URL.

Comment: In fact, under iis I created a folder under the web project where, after converting it into application, I entered the MVC project. now I'm trying to figure out how to integrate OWIN mvc application with that of the webform, as accessed from webform.